# How to execute shell commands as a different user with only sudo password?

Tags: bash

I'd like to test a Webhook and is there a way how one can execute a shell command as a different user with sudo?

As root I could do something like:

```
su - www-data -c 'cd /var/www/xml/tei_staged && git pull origin master 2>&1'
```

With

```
sudo -u www-data 'cd /var/www/xml/tei_staged && git pull origin master 2>&1'
```

I get an error:

> sudo: cd /var/www/xml/tei_staged && git pull origin master 2>&1:
>   command not found

Comment: Have you read the sudo man page? The information you need is right there waiting for you.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, it's somewhat stupid but this works and maybe it's useful for someone else who is slow on the uptake, too:

```
cd /var/www/xml/tei_staged && sudo -u www-data git pull origin master 2>&1
```